# Raspberry pi: generate and play tone from python code (with sox)

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, playback, sox

I am building a simple GUI with Raspberry, TKinter, and sox, using python 3.
I want to play a tone, generated on the fly, every time a button in the GUI is pressed. Here's the code:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Label, Button
import os

class MyFirstGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Random Tone Generator")

        self.label = Label(master, text="Press Generate and enjoy")
        self.label.pack()

        self.generate_button = Button(master, text="Generate", command=self.generate)
        self.generate_button.pack()

        self.close_button = Button(master, text="Close", command=master.quit)
        self.close_button.pack()

    def generate(self):
        os.system('play -n -c1 synth 3 sine 500')

root = Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Here is the call from terminal to this script

```
sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/soundtest.py
```

And here the error I get if I try to push the button "Generate"

```
play FAIL formats: can't open output file `default': select_format error: Operation not permitted
```

If I try the same command ('play -n -c1 synth 3 sine 500') it works as expected.

I searched for few hours now and I tried solutions using *subprocess*, which give back the same problem, and solutions related to playing files, while I need to generate tones on the spot because in the future they will be randomly generated.

My question boils down to: 
1) why the command that works in the terminal does not work within the python script
2) how do I make it work so that I can generate tones directly from the script? 
I read somewhere I can't find anymore that one might need to specify the audio driver during the call from the script. But I wouldn't know how.

EDIT: I have an HiFiberry DAC+ pro sound card installed, which is automatically set to be the default one (instead of the vc4-hdmi)

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: vc4hdmi [vc4-hdmi], device 0: MAI PCM vc4-hdmi-hifi-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sndrpihifiberry [snd_rpi_hifiberry_dacplus], device 0: HiFiBerry DAC+ Pro HiFi pcm512x-hifi-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Thanks
Ant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution.

I needed to specify the sound card to use and I did so by changing the line

```
os.system('play -n -c1 synth 3 sine 500')
```

into this

```
os.system("AUDIODRIVER=alsa AUDIODEV=hw:1,0 play -n -c1 synth 3 sine 500")
```

where the *AUDIODEV=hw:1,0* is the number of my sound card derived from 
`aplay -l`